# I get PHP error when I try to upload some pdf files when other work great

Tags: file-uploads

I tried to disable XSS filter but it does not help. I use file manager to upload files.
Errors I get:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: file_id

Filename: cp/content_files_modal.php

Line Number: 199

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: mime_type

Filename: cp/content_files_modal.php

Line Number: 388

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: file_name

Filename: cp/content_files_modal.php

Line Number: 392

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: upload_location_id

Filename: cp/content_files_modal.php

Line Number: 393

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: file_name

Filename: cp/content_files_modal.php

Line Number: 398

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: file_size

Filename: cp/content_files_modal.php

Line Number: 408

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: upload_location_id

Filename: cp/content_files_modal.php

Line Number: 413

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: modified_date

Filename: cp/content_files_modal.php

Line Number: 202

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: replace

Filename: cp/content_files_modal.php

Line Number: 205

File Already Exists:
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: original_name

Filename: core/Loader.php(727) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 4


A file with that filename already exists. You can either choose a new name and the file will be renamed, or you can use the same name and the existing file will be overwritten.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: hidden

Filename: core/Loader.php(727) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 7



A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: original_name

Filename: core/Loader.php(727) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 8

" class="text" />.
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: file_extension

Filename: core/Loader.php(727) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 8
```

Any help appreciated,

Thank you,

Wojtek

Comment: Could you please edit your question and put your errors in code blocks so they're easier to read? Use the help section of this site for more info: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: I notice that towards the bottom of the error message is " class="text" /> Is this something in your HTML perhaps? Just wondering if there is something bizarre going on in the file name which is breaking the code? Long shot, I know.

Comment: I'm definitely thinking that this is an environment issue. I will probably be able to track this down tomorrow if no one gets to it (guarantee Blatant will try and steal it from me!!).

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this? Having the same issue with a client of ours when uploading a file which already exists. Suspect it may have something to do with a space in the filename, but getting the same errors on the File Upload screen.

Comment: do you have Assets on your site?

Comment: This is clearly not an attempted answer to the question.

Comment: The issue can happen if you have Assets module and u try to upload & replace the file in EE file manager.  This bug was reported to P&T at Sep 10, confirmed for fixing in next release. But no new release still :(  As q solution - disable assets hook for files_after_delete;

Answer (score 0):

This issue can happen if you have P&T Assets module and you try to upload & replace the file in EE file manager. This bug was reported to P&T at Sep 10, confirmed for fixing in next release.

As a solution - disable assets hook for `files_after_delete`.